# How to initialize a non-const attribute of a const object with a const value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to instantiate a const object of my class, and initialize its members pointers from const pointers. Is that possible? How to do it?

I have something of the kind:

```
class A:
    public Base
{
public:
    A():
        v(nullptr)
    {}

    virtual void f() override
    {}

private:
    my_type *v;

    friend void f(const my_type& orig)
    {
        // How to create a "const A" with "v == &orig" ?
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether an object itself is constant and whether any of its class members are constant, are two completely separate topics.

Whether or not a members of a class can be initialized in a particular way does not depend on whether a particular instance of the class is constant, or not.

A pointer to a constant object cannot be used to initialize a pointer to a non-constant object. Your class member:

```
my_type *v;
```

is a pointer to a non-constant object (presuming that `my_type` itself is not a constant type).

As such, this pointer cannot be initialized to point to a constant object.

Whether or not some instance of the class, containing this member, is constant, or not, is not a factor.